# Is it possible to query against arguments passed to a Mockito mocked object?

Tags: java, mockito

I'm learning Mockito at the moment and one of the things I'm doing to consolidate my learning is converting an old JUnit test from using a hand rolled mock class to one which uses Mockito mocks instead.  However, I've run into a situation I'm not sure how to handle.

Specifically, my unit under test constructs a `String` which gets passed to the mocked object as a parameter in a method call on it.  I'd like to test that the `String` is constructed correctly.  The challenge is that part of the `String` is a hash key which is generated internally and changes on every invocation.  One solution that would work would be to get the hash generation under my control and inject a dummy generator for test execution.  However, this is a fair bit of work.

My old hand rolled mock class would store the arguments passed to it which I could query in my test.  This allowed me to query the start and end of the `String` via the following:

```
assertTrue(mockFtpClient.getFilePathAndName().startsWith("/data/inbound/XJSLGG."));
assertTrue(mockFtpClient.getFilePathAndName().endsWith(".pdf"));
```

This was a sufficent enough test for my taste.  So my question is, is it possible using Mockito to query or get a hold of the arguments passed to a method so that i can perform something similiar to the above?

**UPDATE 24/06/2011**:
At this point I have excepted Gnon's answer.  However, I have since discovered something which works better for me.  Namely `ArgumentCaptor`.  Here's how it works:

```
ArgumentCaptor<String> fileNameArgument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
verify(mockFtpClient).putFileOnServer(fileNameArgument.capture());
assertTrue(fileNameArgument.getValue().startsWith(START_FILE_NAME) &&
           fileNameArgument.getValue().endsWith(END_FILE_NAME));
```

The javadoc for Mockito state that `ArgumentCaptor` is generally a better choice when you have a one-off specific argument matching requirement, as I do here.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I didn't know about ArgumentCaptor.

Comment: ArgumentCaptor is going to change my (coding) life!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you need to use **argThat()** in Mockito, that lets you treat a Hamcrest **Matcher** as a verification argument.  Here is the code you use to make custom assertions about a passed-in argument:

```
@Test
public void testname() throws Exception {
    HashReceiver receiver = mock(HashReceiver.class);
    receiver.set("hash");
    verify(receiver).set(argThat(new HashMatcher()));
}

class HashMatcher extends BaseMatcher<String> {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        String hash = (String) item;
        if (hash.startsWith("/data/inbound/XJSLGG.") && hash.endsWith(".pdf"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}

// Mocked
class HashReceiver {
    public void set(String hash) {
    }
}
```

You may be able to use a generic matcher instead, or a combination of generic matchers.

Comment: Thanks Gnon,  I think this solution works really well for what I need.  Shame its so much extra code, but then this isn't a common scenario.

Comment: This is where you'll find the argThat() method: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html#argThat(org.hamcrest.Matcher). Your import should be `import static org.mockito.Matchers.argThat;`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the accepted answer to this question [mockito-how-to-make-a-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/mockito-how-to-make-a-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it) it will show you how to get a hold of the arguments passed to your mock method invocation.

Comment: Not bad, but using the Answer object to get a hold of the input parameter seems a bit backwards to me and I'm not entirely sure it would work with my void method signature.  Thanks though!  I didn't know about `Answer` before.