# Mockito: when Method A.a is called then execute B.b

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, mockito

I'm using Mockito for JUnit tests.
So there is a given class A that is used from the code i want to test:

```
class A{

    public A(){}

    public final String a(String x){
        return "A.a: " + x;
    }

}
```

and i want to replace the Method call A.a with another method call with the same arguments and same type of return value. As you can see, its not possible to override the method a by extending the class as it is final. So what i have now is another class B with the method B.b:

```
class B{

    public B(){}

    public String b(String x){
        return "B.b: " + x;
    }

}
```

Now i want to make sure every time when A.a is called from the code, the return value of B.b is used instead. Is there a possibility to achieve this with Mockito (something like `Mockito.when(A.a(x)).thenReturn(B.b(x));` ) but with the same parameter x, without knowing the value of x?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the scenario you want to test ? Why A.a() is final ? and Why do you want to replace the call of A.a() ?. From what I understand you want to override A.a(), right ?

Comment: I'm testing an Android Library project (i use Robolectric as well, to be able to test Android projects). In this particular case i want to test a Database. The code calls a content resolver, the content provider is defined in the AndroidManifest.xml and i have not found a way to set the content provider programmatically as it is not loaded from the xml when running the tests. So i wanted the code to call the content provider instead of the content resolver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible to override final methods for Mockito-generated mocks, according to [Mockito limits](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_limitations_of_Mockito). But you can use [Powermock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) to hack code at runtime so that Mockito can do its job.

Comment: This gets around the `final` problem and @brice's answer answers the gist of your original question.

Answer (score 23):

Well mockito mocks works by extending the class and overriding the method, which in your case is not possible on `A.a(String)`. If you want this to happen you have to remove the final modifier.

Now assuming `A.a(String)` is not final, what you ask is completely doable with mockito:

### Since Mockito 1.9.5+ and Java 8+

You can use a lambda expression, like:

```
given(mockA.a(anyString())).willAnswer(i -> i.getArguments()[0]);
```

> Where `i` is an instance of `InvocationOnMock`.

### For older versions:

```
given(mockA.a(anyString()).willAnswer(returnOfB(bInstance));

Answer<String> returnOfB(final B bInstance) {
    return new Answer<String>() {
         public String answer(Invocation invocation) {
             String arg = (String) invocation.getActualArguments()[0];
             return bInstance.b(arg);
         }
    };
}
```

Please note this answer has been written on a phone and might have typo, or wrong names, though you should get the idea of what should be done to achieve what you want.

Cheers

Comment: thank you, but its not a solution for me as i cant remove the final modifier. It is some code from the Android SDK.

Comment: @sergej-zagursky has the answer to get around the final modifier problem, but this one answers the gist of your original question.  This is how you base your return value on the value of `x`.

Comment: How do I import the "given"?

Comment: @neves Use `org.mockito.BDDMockito.given` ;)

Comment: Simple version using lambda - check answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/making-a-mocked-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it/2711553#2711553

Answer (score 1):

Basically I took your setup and wrote a Unit-Test with it. What popped up first was an error message that explicitly stated this:

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.

And later in the trace it states that "you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods. Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified."

So according to Mockito you cannot stub final methods, and that's that.

Edit: So you have to either remove the final modifier or, in case you're stuck with this class as it is, find another way around it.