# Mockito - Overriding a method that takes primitive parameters

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class which is subclass of `Context`. I'm unit-testing another class which have dependency to this class, and therefore I've mocked it. However, I need some methods to act as their original behavior, so I'm going to "unmock" them.

One of them is `getAssets()` so I wrote this and it works correctly:

```
Mockito.doReturn(this.getContext().getAssets()).when(keyboard).getAssets();
```

`keyboard` is the mocked instance of the class mentioned.

Since this method takes no parameters, overriding it was pretty simple.

I also need to override `Context.getString(int)` too. The parameter makes things difficult and it being a primitive, makes even more difficult.

I took [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12088675/1385489) and another one, and tried writing this code:

```
Mockito.when(keyboard.getString(Mockito.anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>(){
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable
         Integer arg = (Integer)invocation.getArguments()[0];
         return OuterClass.this.getContext().getString(arg.intValue());
    }
});
```

This compiled and executed, but gave the following exception:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:
Invalid use of argument matchers!
0 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at [...] <The code above>

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:282)
at [...]
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:545)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1551)
```

So the main question is How to override methods in Mockito, which have primitive parameters?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. If you search for `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`, you'll find a bunch of related questions and answers. The problem is you are calling a Mockito method with one Matcher argument and one without, which is not allowed for various reasons.

Comment: Thanks for trying. Yeah, I was searching already and still doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't stub `getString` because it's final.  Mockito can't stub final methods.  Just leave it unstubbed, and you'll get its original implementation.  That's what you want anyway, right?

Comment: Yes I want that, but leaving it as is, results to a `NullPointerException` inside `getString()`! I believe it's because it calls other methods which are stubbed. Thats why I'm trying to relay it from `MockedKeyboard.getString()` to `AndroidTestCase.getContext.getString()`. Isn't this the right way?

Comment: You could try creating a mock with a default answer of `CALLS_REAL_METHODS`, then just stub those methods that you really want to stub.  So `Context mockContext = mock(Context.class, CALLS_REAL_METHODS);`.  You might still get into trouble if one of the methods uses a field that hasn't been initialised.

Comment: Oh, Thanks man, I was searching for such a feature :) This helps for now.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be a `Answer<String>` ?

```
Mockito.when(keyboard.getString(Mockito.anyInt())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>(){
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
         return "foo";
    }
});
```

And you could rename keyboard-->mockContext, that would be more clear ?

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks, I was totally mixed up in my `answer()` method. I corrected it, however, the exception is the same!

Comment: really strange error, are you sure there is no other mock invocation somewhere causing this error ?

Comment: This happens when you create a mocked invocation expectation with mixed parameters : both Mockito.anyXXX and a real parameter (i.e. "foo").

Comment: Yes it's strange. I'm sure, I disabled all tests and just a trivial test with this setUp code remains and still the same error. Searching Internet shows that this exception despite being clear and explaining itself with a good example, shows itself in unrelated situations and the main error could be something else.

Answer (score 0):

As [David Wallace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/david-wallace) noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18942522/1385489), the `Context.getString()` method is final and we know that mockito cannot mock final methods. So overriding it is a bad idea too and will not work.

The `"0 matchers expected, 1 recorded"` info on description of `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`, is a vague way of saying that the method is `final` and we must not try to override it.

However leaving it as is won't help because the object is still a mocked object and the method won't show the expected behavior that we want from a normal object; so this option is also off the table.

At last i decided to change and improve my design. I used [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) and divided the responsibilities of `Context` and `Keyboard` (I'm developing an IME service). In the application itself, I passed the same object of `keyboard` for these two, but in test I mocked the `Keyboard` without any bad side effects and used the `TestCase.getContext()` as the `Context` which eliminated the need to "unmock" its methods.