# Mockito: How do I use getString with mockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-context

I took inspiration from google's sample on how to test your `SharedPreferences` code here by creating a `SharedPreferencesHelper` class:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/unit/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/testing/unittesting/BasicSample/SharedPreferencesHelper.java

You can see that the class uses actual strings hardcoded within the class as the keys to the `sharedPreferences` - here's an extract of the class:

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

    // Keys for saving values in SharedPreferences.
    static final String KEY_NAME = "key_name";
    static final String KEY_DOB = "key_dob_millis";
    static final String KEY_EMAIL = "key_email";

    public boolean savePersonalInfo(SharedPreferenceEntry sharedPreferenceEntry){
        // Start a SharedPreferences transaction.
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(KEY_NAME, sharedPreferenceEntry.getName());
        editor.putLong(KEY_DOB, sharedPreferenceEntry.getDateOfBirth().getTimeInMillis());
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, sharedPreferenceEntry.getEmail());

        // Commit changes to SharedPreferences.
        return editor.commit();
    }
```

When testing this on using their `SharedPreferencesHelperTest` class here, they access the mocked `sharedPreferences` using the same variables defined in the above class:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/blob/master/unit/BasicSample/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/testing/unittesting/BasicSample/SharedPreferencesHelperTest.java

An extract of that class is displayed below:

```
when(mMockSharedPreferences.getString(eq(SharedPreferencesHelper.KEY_NAME), anyString()))
            .thenReturn(mSharedPreferenceEntry.getName());
    when(mMockSharedPreferences.getString(eq(SharedPreferencesHelper.KEY_EMAIL), anyString()))
            .thenReturn(mSharedPreferenceEntry.getEmail());
    when(mMockSharedPreferences.getLong(eq(SharedPreferencesHelper.KEY_DOB), anyLong()))
            .thenReturn(mSharedPreferenceEntry.getDateOfBirth().getTimeInMillis());
```

The way google does this allowed them to bypass the issue of using a `context` to pull a string out of the **string.xml** resource file and query it inside `sharedPreferences` like how it is normally suppose to happen by using `getString()`, ie:

```
mSharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.name),"");
```

However, I have read that it is not possible to use `context.getString` as it is a final method and mockito cannot mock final methods:

[Mockito - Overriding a method that takes primitive parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941509/mockito-overriding-a-method-that-takes-primitive-parameters/18942522#18942522)

How can I then use mockito to unit test any methods with `getString`? Any method with `getString` will not work and my unit test will fail.

This is my class that I have written for `SharedPreferences` and I would like to test it with the `sharedPreferences` keys written with `getStrings`:

```
public class SharedPreferencesHelper {

    // The injected SharedPreferences implementation to use for persistence.
    private final SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    private Context context;

    public SharedPreferencesHelper(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, Context context) {
        mSharedPreferences = sharedPreferences;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean saveName(String name) {
        // Start a SharedPreferences transaction.
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(context.getString(R.string.name), name);
        return editor.commit();
    }

    public String fetchName() {
        // Start a SharedPreferences transaction.
        return mSharedPreferences.getString(context.getString(R.string.name),"");
    }

    public boolean saveGender(String gender) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(context.getString(R.string.gender), gender);
        return editor.commit();
    }

}
```

This is the test that I have written for the above class - it is very similar to google's SharedPreferencesHelperTest:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class SharedPreferencesHelperTest {

    private static final String TEST_NAME = "Test name";

    private SharedPreferencesHelper mMockSharedPreferencesHelper;

    @Mock
    SharedPreferences mMockSharedPreferences;
    @Mock
    SharedPreferences.Editor mMockEditor;
    @Mock
    MockContext context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Create a mocked SharedPreferences.
        mMockSharedPreferencesHelper = createMockSharedPreference();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSaveName() throws Exception {
        boolean success = mMockSharedPreferencesHelper.saveName(TEST_NAME);
        Timber.e("success " + success);
        assertThat("Checking that name was saved... returns true = " + success,
                success, is(true));
        String name = mMockSharedPreferencesHelper.fetchName();
        Timber.e("name " + name);
        assertThat("Checking that name has been persisted and read correctly " + name,
                TEST_NAME,
                is(name));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a mocked SharedPreferences.
     */
    private SharedPreferencesHelper createMockSharedPreference() {
        // Mocking reading the SharedPreferences as if mMockSharedPreferences was previously written
        // correctly.
        when(mMockSharedPreferences.getString(Matchers.eq("name"), anyString()))
                .thenReturn(TEST_NAME);
        when(mMockSharedPreferences.getString(Matchers.eq("gender"), anyString()))
                .thenReturn("M");
        // Mocking a successful commit.
        when(mMockEditor.commit()).thenReturn(true);
        // Return the MockEditor when requesting it.
        when(mMockSharedPreferences.edit()).thenReturn(mMockEditor);
        return new SharedPreferencesHelper(mMockSharedPreferences, context);
    }
}
```

Running the test fails as I have used `getString` in my `SharedPreferencesHelper` class. If I hard coded the keys, I will not get the error, i.e.:

```
public String fetchName() {
    // Start a SharedPreferences transaction.
    return mSharedPreferences.getString("name","");
}
```

One should not hard-code strings within the code so how do I solve this dilemma?

Answer (score 6):

You could solve this issue by not using the `Context` to get the string resource, but the `Resources` class. `Resources` has the same `getString` method but it is not final.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int)

Alternatively you could try out Robolectric, which would solve this issue, because they implement the context.

http://robolectric.org/

Answer (score 2):

**2017.06 answer:**

I followed jbarat's advice to use Robolectric. It's a bit steep curve to get started because things get changed/deprecated/removed/incompatible with every version of Robolectric/Android Studio.

Here's more or less what I did to make it work, using Android Studio 2.3.3 and Robolectric 3.3.2:

- All the methods in your code that are using `getString` should accept `Context` as a first parameter, to make it mockable
- Test needs to be annotated properly, so that they run with Robolectric, and not default JUnit runner
- Test needs to inject mocked `Context` provided by Robolectric
- Android Studio needs to be configured, see

  - http://robolectric.org/getting-started/#building-with-android-studio
  - https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric.github.io/pull/41/files

`build.gradle`:

```
testCompile "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3.2"
testCompile "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.3.2"
```

`MyClass.java`:

```
public static String myGetString(Context context) {
    return context.getString(R.string.my_string);
}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, packageName = "com.myapplication", sdk = 19)
public class MyTest {
    private Context mockContext;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // inject context provided by Robolectric
        mockContext = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Test
    public void test_myGetString() {
        assertEquals("MY STRING", MyClass.myGetString(mockContext));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To enabling mocking of final methods you need Mockito v2 and follow the instructions here
[Mock the unmockable: opt-in mocking of final classes/methods](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What's-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods)

> create a file in `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing a single line:
>
> ```
> mock-maker-inline
> ```

Once you do this you can mock getString() `when(mMockContext.getString(R.string.string_name)).thenReturn("Mocked String");`

Comment: It seems that this does not work with Android, `getString` always returns `null` (tested with Gradle 3.3.2 and Mockito 2.23.4). This could give an explanation why (they suggest Mockito variants made for Android): https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/mock-final-and-static-methods-on-android-devices-b383da1363ad

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is one of the possibility to mock string resources.

```
applicationMock = Mockito.mock(BaseApplication::class.java)
`when`(applicationMock.getString(R.string.primary_contact)).thenReturn("Primary Contact")
```

add this to the test class

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
```