# Mockito: How to get the arguments passed to a method when the return type of the method is void

Tags: java, mockito

I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/mockito-how-to-make-a-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it), but my problem is that my `myFunction` returns `void` instead of an Object. So I get errors at

`when(mock.myFunction(anyString()))`

saying

```
when (java.lang.Void) in Mockito cannot be applied 
to   (void)
```

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: This [site](http://googletesting.blogspot.de/2014/03/whenhow-to-use-mockito-answer.html) may help you.

Comment: Does `doNothing().when(mock).myFunction(anyString())` work for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have the same answer in a comment on the question, but just to make it easier for future readers to see, here it is.

`doNothing().when(mock).myFunction(anyString());`

in order to be able to handle the `void` return type.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this can be found in my answer to that other post that you linked to.

```
doAnswer(returnsFirstArg()).when(mock).myFunction(anyString());
```

where the `returnsFirstArg()` method is static in the `AdditionalAnswers` class.