# How to pass parameters to a mock object

Tags: java, mockito

I have a class

```
class SearchCriteria
{  
    someEnum with values like "A","B"
    int id;
}
```

I want to mock a Delgeate with one method as

```
class Delegate 
{
    int getSomeStuff(SearchCriteria search) 
    { 
         //call dao and return count   
    }    
}
```

How do I pass SearchCriteria using Mock

```
Delegate mock; 
when(mock.getSomeStuff(??))thenReturn(5);
```

Here for different Use cases of SearchCriteria  , I want different values to be returned

So if enum in SearchCriteria   is set to A thenReturn 0 and in B then return 1 ...etc

How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
when(mock.getSomeStuff(CriteriaA)).thenReturn(0);   
when(mock.getSomeStuff(CriteriaB)).thenReturn(1);
```

An alternative is to [provide a method to be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/mockito-how-to-make-a-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it) when your mock is invoked upon, using this construct:

```
   when(mock.getSomeStuff(any(Criteria.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<Integer>{
        @Override
        public Integer answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
           // inspect args in invocation and return
           // ...
        }
   });
```

which allows you to perform more complex responses.

and inspect upon the arguments provided.

Comment: getSomeStuff expects an Object ..which may be comprised of Enum(s) and may be other Primitive / Class .. how it will work in the scenario when multiple combination has to be fed

Comment: Note my second solution, which allows you to inspect the criteria and return a suitable result

Answer (score 0):

If you need to inspect the parameter, then you can just can use a fake implementation, like:

```
Delegate mock = new Delegate() {
    public int getSomeStuff(SearchCriteria search) {
        // Check search param
        return 0;
    }
};
```