# Dynamic chaining "thenReturn" in mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, chaining, method-chaining

I have a Tuple mock class, whose getString(0) and getString(1) methods are expected to be called n times. Instead of writing something like,

```
when(tuple.getString(0)).thenReturn(logEntries[0]).thenReturn(logEntries[1])...thenReturn(logEntries[n - 1])
```

manually, I tried the following:

```
OngoingStubbing stubbingGetStringZero = when(tuple.getString(0)).thenReturn(serviceRequestKey);
OngoingStubbing stubbingGetStringOne = when(tuple.getString(1)).thenReturn(logEntries[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    stubbingGetStringZero = stubbingGetStringZero.thenReturn(serviceRequestKey);
    stubbingGetStringOne = stubbingGetStringOne.thenReturn(logEntries[i]);
}
```

The expected result is that all calls to `tuple.getString(0)` should return the String `serviceRequestKey` and each call to `tuple.getString(1)` should return a different String `logEntries[i]` ie. ith invocation of tuple.getString(1) returns ith element of logEntries array.

However, due to some odd reason, things are getting mixed up, and second invocation to `tuple.getString(1)` returns the String `serviceRequestKey` instead of `logEntries[1]`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, the right way to do this would be:

```
import org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers;

String[] logEntry = // Some initialization code
List<String> logEntryList = Arrays.asList(logEntry);
when(tuple.getString(1)).thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf(logEntryList));
```

On each invocation, successive elements of logEntry array are returned. Thus, ith invocation of `tuple.getString(1)` returns ith element of logEntry array.

P.S: The example in documentation of returnsElementsOf (as of this writing) is not updated (it still uses ReturnsElementsOf example): http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsElementsOf(java.util.Collection)it

Answer (score 6):

If I understood well, you want your mock to return different results depending on the invocation (meaning result1 when invoked for the first time, result2 when invoked for the second time etc)- this can be accomplished with such thing

```
Mockito.when(tuple.getString(0)).thenReturn(serviceRequestKey,logEntries[0],logEntries[1])
```

With this you will get serviceRequestKey on first invocation, logEntries[0] on second etc...

If you want something more sophisticated, like change the return depending on the param in the method use thenAnswer() as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/mockito-how-to-make-a-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it)

Comment: Well, your answer is correct and essentially a shorthand version of multiple thenReturn. The only thing is the number of invocations in my case is a bit large ~ 15-20. So, I will have to write that many parameters for thenReturn. Was hoping to find a solution using a for loop or something.

Comment: thenReturn method acceps the String[], so you can create the array in the loop as you wanted and pass it then.

Comment: thenReturn() only accepts multiple String parameters, not an array. See: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html. Anyway, your comment helped me look in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @gjain, varargs are just syntactic sugar on top of arrays, so String[] would work well. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925153/can-i-pass-an-array-as-arguments-to-a-method-with-variable-arguments-in-java for more details.

Comment: @MikaelOhlson Problem is that you need to go on a long walk with Mockito's syntax because you need to cut the first argument off the array in order to fit: thenReturn(T value, T... values), then subList, and it's a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I know that post is older, but maybe it helps:

```
    OngoingStubbing<Boolean> whenCollectionHasNext = when(mockCollectionStream.hasNext());
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        whenCollectionHasNext = whenCollectionHasNext.thenReturn(true);
    }
    whenCollectionHasNext = whenCollectionHasNext.thenReturn(false);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Here is the error message: "You probably stored a reference to OngoingStubbing returned by when() and called stubbing methods like thenReturn() on this reference more than once."

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand Mockito well enough to understand your example, but wouldn't you want something like:

```
Mockito.when(tuple.getString(0)).thenReturn(serviceRequestKey);
for(int i = 0;i < logEntries.length;i++) {
    Mockito.when(tuple.getString(i+1)).thenReturn(logEntries[i]);
}
```

Comment: I have clarified the question further. Actually, I want different result from each invocation of tuple.getString(1). Note that it is always tuple.getString(1), the index does not change.