# How to make mockito return values from a list for each iteration on a for loop

Tags: java, mockito

Supose this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    long numFound = barObj.getNumFound();
    total += numFound;
}
```

I want to make `getNumFound()` return values from a list for each iteration on the loop using mockito. How do I do that?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you ***don't*** do that.  How is the list being determined in your method to begin with?  Where's it coming from?  You should inject that into your test instead.

Comment: Add more details about your test setup, what do you mock with mockito etc.

Comment: Are you trying to mock `fooList` or `barObj`?

Comment: I changed the for loop format, now it should be more clear. Btw im mocking barObj.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Enumerating list in mockito's thenReturn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33310960/java-enumerating-list-in-mockitos-thenreturn)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would write the following:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf(myList))
       .when(myMock).myMethod(... whatever ...);
```

This uses the `Answer` described [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsElementsOf(java.util.Collection)) to return elements of the list, one after the other.