# How to get mocked method to return different values (from an array) for any args?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I have a method findSubmission. Imagine I have possible return values in an array submission. Right now, I am returning by their indices. But I would like to return all the values of the submission one after the other without using their indices like the way I do right now.

```
when(submissionService.findSubmission(Mockito.anyLong())).thenReturn(submission[0], submission[1], submission[2], submission[3], submission[4])
```

Comment: Almost but not quite a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/49930467

Comment: Also, best to go ahead and get in the habit of formatting your code

Comment: Done! Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
import org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers;

when(submissionService.findSubmission(Mockito.anyLong())).thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf(Arrays.asList(submission)));
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, guys!