# Java mockito - how to add return statement in a loop?

Tags: junit, mockito

```
when(/* some method call*/).thenReturn(mockFetchReturn).thenReturn(mockFetchReturn2)
            .thenReturn(mockFetchReturn3);
```

This is working fine and I am able to call mocked method three times with different output. But my output list can change for each test scenario and I couldn't find how this can be done in a loop based on different returns.
For e.g. If I pass a list of 10 mockFetchReturn3 objects then there should be 10 return statements.

Comment: `when` returns an object (probably something called `Expectation` or something similar). Your can do the `thenReturn` method chaining due to each method returning the same object. Save the object, and you can call this in a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic chaining "thenReturn" in mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010390/dynamic-chaining-thenreturn-in-mockito)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just code for the answer provided in comment:

```
OngoingStubbing stubbing = when(/* some method call*/);
for (int i = 0; ...) {
   stubbing = stubbing.thenReturn(mockFetchReturn(i));
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass a list to

```
List<String> answers = Arrays.asList(mockFetchReturn, mockFetchReturn, ...);
when(/* some method call*/).thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsElementsOf(logEntryList));
```

Also see [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010390/dynamic-chaining-thenreturn-in-mockito)

Comment: First example returns `org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Incorrect use of API detected˙`  in mockito 3.11.2

Comment: feel free to fix code if you find out the issue. Anyway first example is probably worst way to solve this.