# Mockito - returning the same object as passed into method

Tags: java, mockito

Let's imagine I have a following method in some service class:

```
public SomeEntity makeSthWithEntity(someArgs){
    SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity();
    /**
     * here goes some logic concerning the entity
     */
    return repository.merge(entity);
}
```

I'd like to test the behaviour of this method and thus want to mock the `repository.merge` in following manner:

```
when(repository.merge(any(SomeEntity.class))).thenReturn(objectPassedAsArgument);
```

Then mocked repository returns that what `makesSthWithEntity` passed to it and I can easily test it.

Any ideas how can I force mockito to return **`objectPassedAsArgument`** ?

Comment: You mean when(repository.merge(any(SomeEntity.class))).thenReturn(entity); ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a mocked method return an argument that was passed to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/making-a-mocked-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can implement an `Answer` and then use `thenAnswer()` instead.

Something similar to:

```
when(mock.someMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return invocation.getArguments()[0];
    }
});
```

Of course, once you have this you can refactor the answer into a reusable answer called `ReturnFirstArgument` or similar.

Comment: Already exists in mockito : `AddtionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()`

Comment: You can still shorten the code with `thenAnswer(i -> i.getArguments()[0])`. Great solution, and BTW the `AddtionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()` is giving me some errors.

Comment: Great, this give me an ocean of opportunities. Thanks

Answer (score 138):

You can use the Mockito shipped answers:

```
when(mock.something()).then(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg())
```

Where `AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg()` could be statically imported.

Comment: Nice!  I didn't expect this to be common enough to be built in, never mind "returnsSecondArg", etc.  I also like using the `then()` alias here as it reads better.

Comment: Yes ;) we've introduced `then` alias to read better when used in combination with static factory method for custom answers.

Comment: @MarkPeters, `AdditionalAnswers` is for "less common answers", it says in the documentation

Comment: @smac89 but common enough ;)

Answer (score 13):

It can be done easy with Java 8 lambdas:

```
when(mock.something(anyString())).thenAnswer(i -> i.getArguments()[0]);
```