# Return argument of mocked method as a result

Tags: java, junit, mockito

The simplest example:I have the following method:

```
public String testMethod(String arg){
    .....
}
```

I want to mock this method to return passed argument as a result. For example:

```
testMethod("aString") returns "aString"
testMethod("anotherString") returns "anotherString"
```

I know I can hard code this behavior, but I want it generic.

Comment: `String func(String arg){ return arg; }`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mockito: How to make a method return an argument that was passed to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/mockito-how-to-make-a-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write your own [`Answer`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html):

```
when(mock.testMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(new Answer<String>() {
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        return invocation.getArgumentAt(0, String.class);
    }
});
```

Or:

```
when(mock.testMethod(anyString()))
    .thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.<String>returnsFirstArg());
```

Comment: Thanks for you response, it solves my problem!
The second solution returns null, but the first solution fits perfectly.
I have tried something similar:
when(mock.testMethod(anyString())).thenReturn(returnsArgAt(0).toString());
But it doesn't work in my case, may be I did something wrong.

Comment: @Jean: Avoid `ClonesArguments`, as it's an internal package; AdditionalAnswers is the way to go there. Aram: `thenReturn` will always calculate and save a value at stubbing time, which is long before you need it. Using `thenAnswer(returnArgAt(0))` tells Mockito to _use an Answer to calculate the value_, specifically _the Answer given by `returnsArgAt(0)`_, so you shouldn't call `toString` there.

Comment: @JeffBowman You are right, I did not notice it was internal. I removed it and switched to ``AdditionalAnswers``.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement your own `Answer`:

```
Answer<String> returnArgAnswer = new Answer<String>() {
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        return (String) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
    }
};

SomeClass x = mock(SomeClass.class);
Mockito.when(x.testMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(returnArgAnswer);
```

Then, calling `x.testMethod` with any string will return that string.

Answer (score 2):

This already exists built-in on Mockito 1.9.5 and later, as [`returnsFirstArg`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#returnsFirstArg()).

```
when(mock.testMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(returnsFirstArg());
```

You may wish to avoid using `ClonesArguments` directly, as it's in the internal package `org.mockito.internal.stubbing.answers`. Mockito's static factory classes are the preferred way to get to Mockito's predefined answers and matchers.

Answer (score 1):

Put it like this:

```
public String testMethod(String arg){
    return arg;
}
```

Comment: I need to mock this behavior for test, I don't want to change code for it.

Comment: @AramAslanyan I'm not really secure about what do you mean with "mock". I'm not an english speaker and I search in the translator and I think it don't have sense for me in this sentence.

Comment: It is term in Mockito framework: you mock object when you want to have fake object with similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Generic-generic? You can use the following

```
public <T> T testMethod(T arg) {
    return arg;
}
```

Then you can use it with any type,

```
String s = testMethod("someString");
Integer i = testMethod(0);
```

Comment: No, this is _not_ what OPs wants. He wants to mock that method to return exactly that String he passes to that method. With "generic" he meant, that he don't want to use String literals for the `when(...).then(...)` statement.