# Mockito: using a method in "thenReturn" to return a mock doesn't work

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have encountered what I assume might be a bug with Mockito, but was wondering if anyone else can shed light as to why this test doesn't work.

Basically, I have two objects, like this:

```
public class FirstObject {
    private SecondObject secondObject;
    public SecondObject getSecondObject() { return secondObject; }
}

public class SecondObject {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

The first object is mocked via annotation and the before method:

```
@Mock
FirstObject mockedFirstObject;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

The second object is mocked in a method:

```
public SecondObject setupMockedSecondObject() {
    SecondObject secondObject = Mockito.mock(SecondObject.class);
    Mockito.when(secondObject.getName()).thenReturn("MockObject");
    return secondObject;
}
```

When `thenReturn` contains a direct call to this method to setup and obtain a mock of the second object, it fails:

```
@Test
public void notWorkingTest() {
    Mockito.when(mockedFirstObject.getSecondObject()).thenReturn(setupMockedSecondObject());
    Assert.assertEquals(mockedFirstObject.getSecondObject().getName(), "MockObject");
}
```

But, when the mock returned by the same method is assigned to a local variable, which is used in `thenReturn`, it works:

```
@Test
public void workingTest() {
    SecondObject mockedSecondObject = setupMockedSecondObject();
    Mockito.when(mockedFirstObject.getSecondObject()).thenReturn(mockedSecondObject);
    Assert.assertEquals(mockedFirstObject.getSecondObject().getName(), "MockObject");
}
```

Are we doing something wrong or is this indeed a bug/limitation in Mockito? Is there a deliberate reason for this not working?

Comment: This is likely due to how Mockito implements its `when`/`thenReturn` (or other) calls. You're breaking that chain by invoking another `when`/`thenReturn` cycle before calling the previous `thenReturn`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

This is indeed a limitation of Mockito, and it is referenced [in their FAQ](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/FAQ#can-i-thenreturn-an-inlined-mock-):

> #### Can I `thenReturn()` an inlined `mock()`?
>
> Unfortunately you cannot do this:
>
> ```
> when(m.foo()).thenReturn(mock(Foo.class));
> //                         ^
> ```
>
> The reason is that detecting unfinished stubbing wouldn't work if we allow above construct. We consider is as a 'trade off' of framework validation (see also previous FAQ entry). However you can slightly change the code to make it working:
>
> ```
> //extract local variable and start smiling:
> Foo foo = mock(Foo.class);
> when(m.foo()).thenReturn(foo);
> ```

The workaround, as mentioned, is to store the desired returned value in a local variable, like you have done.

The way I understand it is that Mockito validates the usage you make of it every time you call its methods. When another method is called during an on-going stubbing process, you are breaking its validation process.

Comment: Now you can!
This is an old answer.

Comment: @HamzehSoboh No you can't because this method is run before, and we want it executed after as required by "then return". This is a limitation because states can't be updated by spied foo() method before thenReturn is executed. The thenReturn parameter can't benefit from the state set by the spied or mocked method.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a method in `thenReturn`, but you can in `thenAnswer`
Your code will be called after the when condition will occur,
unlike  any workaround based on `thenReturn`

Thus you  could write:

```
@Test
public void nowWorkingTest() {
    Mockito.when(mockedFirstObject.getSecondObject()).thenAnswer(new Answer<Map>() {
        @Override
        public Map answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            return setupMockedSecondObject();
        }
    });
    Assert.assertEquals(mockedFirstObject.getSecondObject().getName(), "MockObject");
}
```

Let find another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31012793/1767316)

Comment: Yes as @user1767316 suggested, have to use thenAnswer for mocked object method to return another mocked object. 

In Kotlin, you can do similar as in one-liner as:

`
       `when`(mockedFirstObject.getSecondObject).thenAnswer { 
                    mock<SecondObject> { it.name = "MockObject" } 
         }
`

Comment: Shorter via lambda: replace `.thenReturn(returnValue)` with `.thenAnswer(i -> returnValue)`.

Answer (score -3):

```java
@Test
public void testAuthenticate_ValidCredentials() throws FailedToAuthenticateException {

    String username = "User1";
    String password = "Password";
    /*Configure Returning True with when...thenReturn configuration on mock Object - Q5*/
   //Write your code here
    assertTrue(authenticator.authenticateUser(username, password));
}
```