# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, matcher

I have multiple mock statements in my test class and everything works fine. I am adding a new statement for a DAO mocking as :

```
 Mockito.when(myDAO.saveOrUpdate(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Mockito.any());

But I get exception as :

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:  Invalid use of argument matchers!
```

I have used argument matchers and not raw values so I have not mixed anything.What can be the cause here?

Comment: why would you want to return `Mockito.any()`?

Comment: i can return new dummy object also. But wana know why this is not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockito: using a method in "thenReturn" to return a mock doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005168/mockito-using-a-method-in-thenreturn-to-return-a-mock-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called an argument matcher outside a call to when or verify, which is illegal.

See [Argument matchers](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.5.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#argument_matchers):

> Matcher methods like `any()`, `eq()` **do not** return matchers. Internally, they record a matcher on a stack and return a dummy value (usually null). This implementation is due to static type safety imposed by the java compiler. The consequence is that you cannot use `any()`, `eq()` methods outside of verified/stubbed method.

See also [How do Mockito matchers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work)

Comment: why does it work in some cases and not all

Comment: @user124 this is not a precise question. Please show an example where the behaviour differs, and in your view it shouldn't.