# During running test in the debug mode in Android studio I see no way to see my println output (test not running in emulator or on a device)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

During running a test in the debug mode I see no way to see my `println` output. It is not an Android Test so it is not running in emulator and/or on the device.

I am using Android Studio 3.5.2.

How can I see what was displayed by `println` commands? I tried:

- Logcat (not working as expected, as I am not running tests in emulator or on the device)
- Debug tab, and checked both Debugger and Console subtabs
- Terminal tab - show new terminal without program output
- Build - as expected, nothing relevant

I also tried:

- restarting Android Studio
- restarting system
- restarting Android Studio with clearing caches
- looking for an alternative IDE, it seems that Android Studio has a de facto monopoly (Eclipse is the only potential alternative, but for now I am stuck with Eclipse crashing at startup and discovery that my OS version is EOL, so now I am going to upgrade from Lubuntu 16.04 )

To avoid XY problem: I want to see my `println` output as I run into a bug in a debugger and state of my variables is hidden - see ["Variables are not available" appearing sometimes during debugging, on stepping through program (Android Studio 3.5+)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59287737/variables-are-not-available-appearing-sometimes-during-debugging-on-stepping)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you use `println` instead of `log.d`?

Comment: @gkpln3 Tests are not running on the Android device or emulator, I thought that `Log.d` and its friends will not work.  I just tried and it is not appearing in any place that I see.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37190243/why-log-d-print-nothing-when-running-android-local-unit-test

Comment: @gkpln3 It is not appearing in the log tab (neither `println` nor `log.d`) and Android Studio has now no "Android Monitor" tab (it seems that it is now called "Logcat"). I can attach a screenshot. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: It should appear on Debug->Console.

Comment: Thanks! I now added `System.out.println("aaaa")` test call directly within test function (not within called code). Now I need to figure out what the heck is happening that captures messages.

Comment: In regular tests, logging should be handled by slf4j via a Logger object

Comment: @cricket_007 From what I see slf4j is just a wrapper, so it should not influence whatever console output is visible, right?

Comment: No but you can filter between info, debug, warn, error, etc... Just like Logcat

Comment: Not OP, but I can speak for myself: I'm debugging someone else's code and it's full of calls to `System.out.println()`. I *do* see the output in the "Run" tab if I run the unit test, but there's no output when debugging.