# Mockito - Match any instance implementing an interface, and answer

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

Mocking a class that at some point is called to add an instance of ActionListener (the interface in java.awt.event) with signature

```
public void addActionListener(ActionListener l).
```

Trying to mock the method call to use an answer, so that I can keep track of its ActionListeners, when it is called with anonymously created instances of ActionListener (just like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6746257/2245763)). But I am unable to make it accept any instance of interface ActionListener.

So far I have tried several examples from other questions, to no avail:

```
when(mock.addActionListener(Matchers.<ActionListener>any())).thenAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
            Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
            if (arguments != null && arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] != null) {
                listeners.add((ActionListener) arguments[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
when(mock.addActionListener(any(ActionListener.class))).thenAnswer([..snip..]);
```

All of them give compilation errors saying *Cannot resolve method when(void)*.

**Is there any way to make Matchers.any match against any instance that implements the interface, and use it for the answer? Is it not possible because its return value is void?**

Using Mockito 1.10, powermock 1.6.5 and java 7. (I can't use Java 8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Mockito.doAnswer()`, it is created for methods returning `void`:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object[] arguments = invocation.getArguments();
        if (arguments != null && arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] != null) {
            listeners.add((ActionListener) arguments[0]);
        }
        return null;
    }
}).when(mock).addActionListener(Matchers.<ActionListener>any());
doAnswer([..snip..]).when(mock).addActionListener(any(ActionListener.class))
```

Comment: The first one gives the same compilation error.
The second one did it for me though, Thanks!
I'm having trouble understanding why 
    when(mock.addActionListener(any(Actionlistener.class))).thenAnswer([snip]); 
doesn't work. But if doAnswer is put first, then it works. Care to clarify? Thanks in advance!!