# jmockit return the same object

Tags: java, mocking, testng, jmockit

Can I mock a method using JMockit in a way that it returns the argument that was passed to it?

Consider a signature like this;

```
public String myFunction(String abc);
```

I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/how-can-i-make-a-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it) it is possible to do this using Mockito. But is this doable in JMockit?

Comment: You may find it easier to use JMockit's "[faking](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Faking.html)" capabilities. However, you may want to re-examine your assumptions and figure out whether this is something you really want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JMockit manual](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#delegates) provides some guidance... I really suggest you read it. The construct you are looking for would probably look something like this:

```
@Test
public void delegatingInvocationsToACustomDelegate(@Mocked final DependencyAbc anyAbc)
{
   new Expectations() {{
      anyAbc.myFunction(any);
      result = new Delegate() {
         String aDelegateMethod(String s)
         {
            return s;
         }
      };
   }};

   // assuming doSomething() here invokes myFunction()...
   new UnitUnderTest().doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JMockit can also [capture arguments](http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#singleInvocationCapture):

```
@Test
public void testParmValue(@Mocked final Collaborator myMock) {

    // Set the test expectation.
    final String expected = "myExpectedParmValue";

    // Execute the test.
    myMock.myFunction(expected);

    // Evaluate the parameter passed to myFunction.
    new Verifications() {
        { 
            String actual;
            myMock.myFunction(actual = withCapture());

            assertEquals("The parameter passed to myFunction is incorrect", expected, actual);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @Viv - Could you please choose the answer that best meets your needs?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could not use withCapture() successfully to do what I wanted.