# Multiplying mocked object method parameters

Tags: java, mocking

```
public class Card
{

public double roundMoney(double currencyValue , int digits) {
//some logic for rounding which includes heavy service calling
} 

}
```

Now I want to mock the class and whenever the roundMoney methods is called with parameters I want it to return the product of the parameters

```
Card mycard = mock(Card.class);
when(mycard.roundMoney(anyDouble(), anyInt()).thenReturn( anyDouble() * anyInt() ));
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Err, **why**? You see, in programming, you dont do things because you CAN, but because doing so is meaningful. Test cases should be as easy to understand as possible. Like: setup some mock object, to give a specific response for a specific request. If you need more than that, why use mocks for it? And not say a test-only subclass of whatever service you are using? Meaning: what you are asking for is possible, but adds plenty of complexity to your test code. Be careful about going down that road.

Comment: Also note: your question very much depends on the mocking framework you are using. So: specify which framework you want to use, for example by applying the correct tag for mockito, easymock, or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `thenAnswer` instead of `thenReturn`?  The answer implementation has access to the parameter values being passed.

See: [Making a mocked method return an argument that was passed to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684630/making-a-mocked-method-return-an-argument-that-was-passed-to-it)